# MariaDB won't work after moving database to external drive

Tags: debian, external-hard-drive, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

**Problem:** MariaDB doesn't work after moving database to new location.

**Context:** Connected external hard drive (NTFS) to Raspberry Pi and moved all MariaDB database files to folder on external drive, pointing MariaDB config files to new location. Drive location is `/media/user/extdrive1/`, database files are `/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/`. MariaDB worked perfectly prior to this change, and no longer works.

After `sudo systemctl start mariadb`, `syslog` reports:

`[Warning] Can't create test file /media/user/extdrive1/mysql/server.lower-test`

`#007/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/media/user/extdrive1/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`

What I have tried so far:

- `extdrive1` is set to mount on boot in `fdisk`
- `my.cnf` updated to point to the new location
- `chown -R` rwx for user `mysql` for `/media/user/extdrive1/*`
- RPi has NTFS r/w drive support

Unsure what else to try; would love any input or advice.

Thanks!

Comment: is any reason the drive for mariadb has to be ntfs? This is not really ideal for it

Comment: No particular reason -- that's how it was formatted; could reformat to something else. Do you think that's causing the issue?

Comment: Could be a problem with apparmor, which is fairly notorious for not wanting MySQL to work outside expected directories.

Comment: @symtek try to format it in EXT3 or EXT4, probably it's because it can't properly check ACL with NTFS

Comment: @Magnetic_dud, I've tried formatting a drive to EXT4, mounting it, moving the mysql files over, and chown'ing the drive for mysql, but it's failing with an "Permission denied" error. Any tips?

Comment: @symtek i am not sure... a workaround could be running it inside docker... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/ (publish ports 3306 by adding -p 3306:3306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a permissions hierarchy issue. Permissions were correct on `/media/user/extdrive1/` and `/media/user/extdrive1/mysql`, but mysql couldn't access those addresses because of rwx permission restrictions on `/media` and `/media/user`.

See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237370/mariadb-wont-start-cant-change-dir-errcode-13-permission-denied/237501#237501) for discussion.